# Windows 7 PCs cannot access LAN hosted IIS site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-7, lan

I have an ASP.MVC site hosted on my computer with IIS. This site is using the 8090 port, and i already set the inbound firewall configurations on Control Panel.

Im not able to access this site from all Windows 7 computers and Android Smartphones on LAN, but Im able to access from all Windows XP computers on the same lan.

Answer (score 0):

Since your XP-PCs can access the site, the MVC-site is correctly working.

Check the following things:

- whether the Win7 and Android devices are in the Same LAN, check IP address AND subnet mask.
- whether the MVC-Site is configured to only response to certain IP addresses.